# Can the same database be log-shipping secondary and primary at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

Here is my scenario:

Database DB1 on Server1 is log shipping primary in data center.

Database DB1 on Server2 is log shipping secondary; Server2 is in remote location. Logs are shipped from data center to remote location via shared virtual Jungle Disk drive accessible both from data center and remote location via internet.

In case I fail over to Server2 I would like to have log backups as well.

So my thinking is after configuring DB1 on Server2 as log shipping secondary I would then also configure it as a log shipping primary (even though these log backups won't get shipped anywhere from Server2). When database DB1 on Server2 is in "secondary" mode log backup job will probably be disabled.

Is this a valid use for log shipping?

Comment: You will not be able to setup transaction log backups on the secondary until the database has been recovered. I would recommend either scripting out your log shipping backup job and putting that in a disabled state on the secondary server, or just setup a regularly scheduled transaction log backup job on the secondary which you would just enable when you recover the database.

Comment: I believe you're asking: Can I reverse log shipping in the event if a failover? Short answer is yes (maybe).  If you confirm I'll give some more detail about how to go about it.